# Movie from iTunes: We've determined that your purchase does not meet the conditions for a refund

Tags: itunes, appletv, parental-controls, movie

My toddler bought a random movie on Apple TV by accident (even a foreign language).

I tried to use a form to get a refund (Ask Different how-to):

[how do you cancel a pending purchase in iTunes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/319836/how-do-you-cancel-a-pending-purchase-in-itunes)

which gives me this output after a millisecond:

> We've determined that your purchase does not meet the conditions for a
>   refund.

I also tried this [Request a refund for an App Store or iTunes Store purchase](https://support.apple.com/lv-lv/HT204084)

I don't wish to use phone support. Is it possible to use other process/form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue once before and if I recall correctly, I was able to use the support chat on apple.com to resolve the issue. Give it a try.

Comment: I am in U.S. I usually just go through the SUPPORT tab and answer questions until I get to chat